# Reverse engineering a composer.json file based on existing project library?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, composer-php, deprecated

This is probably a pointless question but figured theres no harm in asking.

I have inherited a website which from what I can gather is using some Zend libraries and Doctrine... I think, excuse my ignorance as I'm not very clued up on the Zend framework.

In anycase I have been asked to update the numerous instances of depreacated code in among it. Which I thought would just have been within the application code so I could just update functions here and there etc etc.

It turns out most of the code needing updated is within the library folder which from what I can gather is all libraries which I would have thought would have been set up using composer but theres no mention of a composer.json file within the codebase.

So im now at a loss as I have a bunch of libraries that I have no idea how to update. Which brings me to my question, what would be the best way to attack this problem?

I was thinking if there was someway to reverse engineer a composer.json file based on the contents of the aforemetnioned library folder, that would be a good start as I could then use that as the basis for replacing the library folder with the updated libraries pulled in by composer but I have a feeling im probably clutching at straws.

To give some idea, this is the top level folder structure of the library folder:

[image]

Given the amount of subfolders within those listed and all the dependencies no doubt involved I would imagine manually updating them would be a nonstarter.

Would be interested to get thoughts on the best course of action here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were in your spot I would create a composer.json and add try to add the libraries from the folder one by one and check if the app still works and fix dependencies one by one, I also see there is a vendor folder in there, that may have been the result of a composer.json which could be easily added in a new composer.json, but you will have to take the libraries one by one.

Comment: Ideally this is what I would have done if I never found afterwards that most of the deprecated code was within files that aren't actually needed by the project. Ended up just removing most of the libraries in the end.