# Can composer automatically "organize" someone else's manually-installed dependencies?

Tags: composer-php

The sites I've been reading mostly guide me on how to use Composer in a **brand new project.**

Is there a way to add Composer mid-project to help me keep track of manually-installed dependencies in a project that I am taking over?  For example, adding Composer to someone else's ongoing project that doesn't use Composer at all (no composer.lock or composer.json) that has a bunch of manually-installed packages already and by using a single Composer command, could magically create a composer.lock and composer.json for me with all of their dependencies included.

Basically I'm asking if Composer can help me automatically "organize" someone else's dependencies with a single command or two, unless all those dependencies had to be configured with Composer beforehand...which would be unfortunate for me trying to reverse engineer and redo it all :(

Comment: Yes, that's possible. If you want to do this depends on how many dependencies you've already installed any other way

Comment: There is no composer.lock or composer.json. How do I use composer to find and organize all their packages if they installed the packages manually without composer?

Comment: Why not use what https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260835/reverse-engineering-a-composer-json-file-based-on-existing-project-library recommends? Also, using Google I've found a lot of articles that deal with this topic. If there is any specific problem with applying them, please ask a more specific question

Comment: Ok I was hoping composer would be able to magically figure this out in a command instead of me having to go through and validate each package one by one, like in the article :P But I have no options...so I will try it this way manually in the link. Thanks!

Comment: You could also start using Composer and keep the existing libraries - such that you only use Composer for those libraries you add from now on

Comment: Fair enough but I'd like to examine and learn a little more about what the previous developer did before moving on so may as well give it a shot  :D

Comment: No, composer can't do this for you. That's the developer's job.